# Excel - Find the last day of a month in a range given a specific year and month value

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I am wondering what Excel/VBA functions I can use to find the last day of a month in a range with the specific year and month input values. 
For example, with '1995' and '3', it should return '3/31/1995'. 
With '1995' and '4', it should return '4/28/1995'.

Note that the actual last day of '04/1995' was '4/30/1995'. I am looking for the last day in the range, '4/28/1995', so I can't just blindly use the EOMONTH function.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are these actual date values? What have you researched? You tagged `VBA` but this is easily done through functions too If you want

Comment: You could use an array formula, like so `=MAX((MONTH($A$1:$A$18)=4)*(A1:A18))`  where I have various dates in a1:a18

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thanks for the comment. What's 4 for?

Comment: Bit quick on the downvotes for my answer - was trying to delete it before the voting started, but had to switch to my phone to do it (work PC always throws an error).  Was working off the statement _For example, with '1995' and '3', it should return '3/31/1995'._ - my answer (`=EOMONTH(DATE(1995,3,1),0)`) would answer that.

Comment: Try `=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(EOMONTH(DATE(1995,4,1),0),$A:$A,1))`.  This figures out the actual last day of the month and then finds the largest number that is less than or equal to that.

Comment: @JunJang does the `MONTH` function not give it away? :o)

Answer (score 1):

Below is a VBA solution that should work and be relatively fast.

I'm adding all items in the range that match the year and month to an `ArrayList`. Then, I'm sorting that list in ascending order and picking the last item in the list (this item should possess the largest value in the set).

This is running in less than a second going through a list of about 800 items.

**Function:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MaxDateInRange(SearchRange As Range, _
                               YearNumber As Long, _
                               MonthNumber As Long) As String
    Dim cell        As Range
    Dim ListIndex   As Long
    Dim List        As Object: Set List = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    
    'Go through all cells, and all items that match the month and year to a list
    For Each cell In SearchRange
        If IsDate(cell) Then
            If Month(cell) = MonthNumber And Year(cell) = YearNumber Then List.Add (cell)
        End If
    Next
    
    'Sort the list ascending, then select the last item in that list
    List.Sort
    ListIndex = List.Count - 1
    
    'Bounds check, to see if anything was found, otherwise return ""
    If ListIndex >= 0 Then
        MaxDateInRange = List(ListIndex)
    Else
        MaxDateInRange = vbNullString
    End If
    
End Function
```

**Usage:**

```
Public Sub Example()
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheets(2).Range("D1:D795")
    Dim t   As Double
    t = Timer
    
    Debug.Print MaxDateInRange(rng, 2019, 3)
    Debug.Print MaxDateInRange(rng, 2019, 4)

    Debug.Print "Process took " & Timer - t
End Sub
```

**Debug Output based on sample data:**

```
2019-03-28
2019-04-25
Process took 0.04296875
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be as follows, I've not fully tested, but could be food for thought.

```
Function get_latest_date(rngInput As Excel.Range, intMonth As Integer, lngYear As Long) As Date

get_latest_date = 0

On Error Resume Next

get_latest_date = Application.Evaluate( _
                "=MAX(IF((YEAR(" & _
                rngInput.Address & _
                ")=" & lngYear & _
                ")*(MONTH(" & _
                rngInput.Address & _
                ")=" & intMonth & ")," & rngInput.Address & "))")

End Function
```

This uses the evaluation of an array formula built from arguments passed in.

I have dummy dates, 10,000 in total, from 2015 to over 2030.  I ran a quick test using the below

```
Function test_get_last_date()

Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim lYear As Long
Dim iMonth As Integer
Dim dTimer As Double

Set r = Range("a1:a10000")

dTimer = Timer

For lYear = 2015 To 2030

    For iMonth = 1 To 12

        Debug.Print get_latest_date(r, iMonth, lYear), "Took : "; Timer - dTimer
        dTimer = Timer

    Next iMonth

Next lYear


End Function
```

This gave these results

```
31/05/2017    Took :  0.02734375 
30/06/2017    Took :  0.015625 
31/07/2017    Took :  0.015625 
31/08/2017    Took :  0.015625 
30/09/2017    Took :  0.01953125
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options :

1. Your data are sorted and you can use match with 1 or -1 third option. As comment from Darren Bartrup-Cook says
2. Else you have to add 2 columns of formula to sort your solution:

Column B, formula `=year(A:A)&MONTH(A:A)` ; concatenate your criteria

Column C, formula from cell C2 `=IFERROR(MAX((B$1:B1=B2)*(C$1:C1)),A2)` ; then expand formula down

The last value in column C for each unique month in column B will be your answers. You can extract results in Column D with formula from cell D2 `=MAX(IF(B:B=B2,C2))` ; then expand formula down

Answer (score 0):

I have separate the date into day, month & year column, then use MAXIFS.

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,C:C,3,D:D,1995)
```